# There Is No Windows Phone in Visual Studio 2015 while working with Xamarin.forms

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

As stated in the title above, there is no windows phone in the dropdown while working with xamarin.forms. I still can run the emulator by right-clicking the project -> debug -> start instance.

But, by doing it that way, I can not choose whether I want to use emulator or device

For better understanding, here is the image [image: no wp emu]

Does anyone know how to show the windows phone in the dropdown?

Comment: Can you make sure your Windows Phone project is loaded. Try to set it as the Startup project and see what happens.